# Delete user-defined indexes for a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Categ12_Items` in Sql Server 2012 that has user-defined indexes created. These are named `index1,index2,index3,index4,index5, index6,index7, index8, index9, index10`. This is just an example, and the last index could be index10 or index11 or index55 or index100, which means starting from index5 there could be any number of indexes created that will always be named sequentially.

The first 4 indexes from index1 through to index4 do not have to be deleted when the table data is repopulated, but all other indexes starting from index5 need to be dropped and recreated.

My problem is how to drop all indexes starting from index5. I could, of course, use  drop individual index as in T-SQL below, but I was trying to do it in one statement. May be there is system defined stored procedure that I am unable to find.

**Question** : Is there a system defined stored procedure that will delete multiple indexes on a table?

```
DROP INDEX index5 on Categ12_Items;
DROP INDEX index6 on Categ12_Items;
DROP INDEX index7 on Categ12_Items;
DROP INDEX index8 on Categ12_Items;
DROP INDEX index9 on Categ12_Items;
DROP INDEX index10 on Categ12_Items;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Disabling vs. Dropping Indexes - Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/disabling-vs-dropping-indexes/)

You can disable the indexes and rebuild them after you are done doing what you need to do.

Disable the indexes:

```
declare @tablename sysname = 'dbo.Categ12_Items';
declare @indexes nvarchar(max);

set @indexes = stuff((
  select
      char(10)+'alter index '+quotename(i.name)+' on '
      +quotename(schema_name(o.schema_id))
      +'.' +quotename(object_name(i.object_id))
      +' disable;'
  from  sys.indexes as i
    inner join sys.objects o 
      on i.object_id = o.object_id
  where o.is_ms_shipped=0
    and i.object_id = object_id(@tablename)
    and i.name not in ('index_1','index_2','index_3','index_4')
  order by i.name
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'');

--select @indexes as disabling_indexes;
exec sp_executesql @indexes;
```

Then do your thing :

```
/* do stuff */
--select 'doing some stuff' as done;
/* done with doing stuff*/
```

Then rebuild the indexes:

```
set @indexes = stuff((
  select
      char(10)+'alter index '+quotename(i.name)+' on '
      +quotename(schema_name(o.schema_id))
      +'.'+quotename(object_name(i.object_id))
      +' rebuild;'
  from  sys.indexes as i
    inner join sys.objects o 
      on i.object_id = o.object_id
  where o.is_ms_shipped=0
    and i.object_id = object_id(@tablename)
    and i.name not in ('index_1','index_2','index_3','index_4')
  order by i.name
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'');

--select @indexes as rebuilding_indexes;
exec sp_executesql @indexes;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RXQYM31744

Here is what the output of the rextester demo is:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                    disabling_indexes                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| alter index [index_5] on [dbo].[Categ12_Items] disable; |
| alter index [index_6] on [dbo].[Categ12_Items] disable; |
| alter index [index_7] on [dbo].[Categ12_Items] disable; |
+---------------------------------------------------------+

+------------------+
|       done       |
+------------------+
| doing some stuff |
+------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                   rebuilding_indexes                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| alter index [index_5] on [dbo].[Categ12_Items] rebuild; |
| alter index [index_6] on [dbo].[Categ12_Items] rebuild; |
| alter index [index_7] on [dbo].[Categ12_Items] rebuild; |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```